# Can't find Java EE perspective on Eclipse Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)

Tags: java, eclipse

I've just recently installed the latest Eclipse version, 2022-03 (4.23.0) and for some reason I can't find the Java EE perspective on eclipse.

I've checked on Window -> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> Other and Java EE is not available. Can someone please help me?

Comment: There are different [IDE packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/). The _Java EE_ perspective exists in the _Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers_ but not in e.g. the _Eclipse IDE for Java Developers_. See _Help > About Eclipse IDE_ for which IDE package do you have.

Comment: So I've chedked and I have this one, "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)". How can I change it to Enterprise Java and Web Developers?

Comment: Install the _Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers_ in addition or instead. The preferences are stored in the workspace that will not be affected by uninstalling the _Eclipse IDE for Java Developers_ and the workspace can be opened also by the _Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers_.

Comment: Thnak you so much!